# Is there another way to reinstall OS X when recovery fails?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, recovery-hd

I have an early 2011 MacBook Pro running 10.7.5 and was trying to update to El Capitan at the advice of Apple Care rep to fix issues I was having.

In midst of install the system totally froze and went black. When I rebooted I got the prohibited symbol so I went to recovery mode to try and reinstall the original operating system (Lion).

Disk Utility didn't even recognize the hard drive so I went to internet recovery. That showed and verified the HDD but when I tried to reinstall OS X, it locks up around 90%. Even checked to status list to verify and it shows an error with the download. Something about not finding a file it needs from what I can tell.

Is there anything I can do or am I dead here? No Apple Store within 200 miles either, so taking it somewhere isn't an option in the near future either.

Comment: At the point you're at, this is what I'd do... Go to my closest friend that has a Mac, download the OS X Installer and create a USB Installer from it. Use it to boot your Mac and install the OS from there.

Comment: "Something about not finding a file it needs..." - that is very strange. What was the exact message?